# COUNTIF work arounds for SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, formula, countif

I've looked at the following questions already posted in this forum, but neither quite address the specific issue I'm having.

[Can I create a COUNTIF calculated column in SharePoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978057/can-i-create-a-countif-calculated-column-in-sharepoint)
[How can I build a CountIF function in SharePoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931380/how-can-i-build-a-countif-function-in-sharepoint)

I am wondering if SharePoint allows you to reference a certain cells data to then look that value up in a column and count how many of that value there are. These would not be set values, which is why the workarounds proposed in the articles above are not working for me.

EX:In our Excel sheet that we are putting into SharePoint, we are using this formula =COUNTIF($C$2:$C$2007,C2007) and we are trying to translate this into SharePoint.

As shown in the image I've attached, we want a frequency column to calculate how many times each value in the Values column occurs. So the results would end up looking like what's in the image.

[Sample Table with Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As26G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, SharePoint does not support **CountIF** function, it is by design.

However, you can use "**Group By**" as a workaround:

1.Go to the list and click on **All Items** >> **Edit current view**

2.On the Edit View page, scroll to "**Group By**" section and select column that your wanted.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for this workaround suggestion. I'm not sure it's going to work for the way we need our list to function and look, but it's SOMEthing, so I really appreciate that.

Comment: Hi, Shey R. Thanks for your reply. I am pleased to be able to help you. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.